# proper notation for union of dictionary

Tags: modeling

Traditionally, our notation has separated out a set and values associated with said set. We'll say something like the state is a tuple of $(V, f)$, where $V$ is a set of control values and $f$ is a vector of their corresponding costs. We then write their union as $(V \cup V', max(f_i, f_i')~\forall i)$. Instead, I want to write it like this:
$V$ is a dictionary of control values to cost. It's union is
$$
V \bigcup_{max} V'
$$
Is that so bad? Or is there some other standard way of doing this that I should be aware of?

Comment: First off, I'm not sure "dictionary" means what you intend to people like me who do not use Python. (I see "dictionary" and think "Merriam-Webster".) Second, your union notation would not mean anything to me. I'm not sure there is a standard way of denoting what you intend.

Comment: What terms do you use besides dictionary? One-to-one table? Lookup table? Key-value set?

Comment: In the context of mathematics (as opposed to coding) I would probably refer to it as either a function or a relation (either one-to-one or many-to-one as appropriate -- I believe the Python definition of "dictionary" rules out one-to-many).